# INNER JOIN entre dos tablas y varios campos

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo un problema al hacer una consulta os pongo en situación

**Tabla1.**

```
Tengo los campos historia , nombre, apellidos, terapeuta1 y terapeuta2
```

**Tabla2.**

```
Tengo los campos id, nombre y apellidos.
```

En terapeuta 1 y terapeuta 2 guardo la id algun usuario de la tabla 2 por ejemplo

**Tabla1:**

```
**historia** = 0
**nombre** = prueba
**apellidos** = prueba
**terapeuta1** = 10
**terpauta2** = 5
```

En terapeuta 1 y 2 tengo las ids que son AI de la tabla 2 que son usuarios registrados y yo quiero obtener a través de esa ID el nombre del usuario, mi código es el siguiente.

```
SELECT pa.*,  pe.nombre AS nombre_personal FROM pacientes pa INNER JOIN personal pe ON terapeuta1 = id AND terapeuta2 = id
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Terapeuta 1 y 2 son llaves foráneas?

Comment: Hola @Aprendiz sí, lo que son foráneas es el campo de terapeuta1, terapeuta2 con la ID de la otra tabla

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si entiendo bien, lo que quieres es el registro de la tabla 1 y los nombres de los terapeutas.

```sql
SELECT pa.*,
    pe1.nombre AS nombre_terapeuta1,
    pe2.nombre AS nombre_terapeuta2
FROM pacientes pa
    INNER JOIN personal pe1 ON pa.terapeuta1 = pe1.id
    INNER JOIN personal pe2 ON pa.terapeuta2 = pe2.id
```

Por supuesto, para añadir el apellido, sería

```
SELECT pa.*,
    pe1.nombre AS nombre_terapeuta1, pe1.apellido AS apellido_terapeuta1,
    pe2.nombre AS nombre_terapeuta2, pe2.apellido AS apellido_terapeuta2
FROM pacientes pa
    INNER JOIN personal pe1 ON pa.terapeuta1 = pe1.id
    INNER JOIN personal pe2 ON pa.terapeuta2 = pe2.id
```

En caso de que los campos terapeuta1 o terapeuta2 pudieran estar vacíos, pero a pesar de eso quisiéramos que saliera el registro, sustituiríamos los inner join por left join

```
SELECT pa.*,
    pe1.nombre AS nombre_terapeuta1,
    pe2.nombre AS nombre_terapeuta2
FROM pacientes pa
    LEFT JOIN personal pe1 ON pa.terapeuta1 = pe1.id
    LEFT JOIN personal pe2 ON pa.terapeuta2 = pe2.id
```

Recuerda que cada entrada de la tabla 2 solo refleja la información de un terapeuta, no de varios. Con tu consulta solo te saldrían las líneas en las que terapeuta1 y terapeuta2 fueran el mismo.